# Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps lint error on presenter layer

Tags: flutter, lint, flutter-lints

Stateless Widget

```
CustomButton.build(
  label: 'login',
  onPressed: () {
    presenter.login(context,username,password);
  },
);
```

Presenter class (where we have all the logic)

```
class Presenter {
  Future<void> login(BuildContext context,String username, String password) async {
    showDialog(context);
    var result = await authenticate(username,password);
    int type = await getUserType(result);
    Navigator.pop(context); // to hide progress dialog
    if(type == 1){
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'a');
    }else if(type == 2){
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'b');
    }
  }

  Future<int> getUserType(User user) async {
    //.. some await function
    return type;
  }
}
```

Now we are getting **Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps.** lint error on our presenter wile hiding the dialog and screen navigation.

What is the best way to fix this lint.

Comment: you return flag from `login` and use on main file to navigate

Answer (score 0):

Don't stock `context` directly into custom classes, and don't use context after async if you're not sure your widget is mounted yet.

I see the better practice to fix it is to set an `onSuccess` method as parameter which will have the    `Navigator.pop(context);` from your UI, but call it inside your main method:

```
  Future<void> login(BuildContext context,String username, String password, void Function() onSuccess) async {
showDialog(context);
var result = await authenticate(username,password);
int type = await getUserType(result);
//Navigator.pop(context); replace this with :
onSuccess.call();
if(type == 1){
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'a');
}else if(type == 2){
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'b');
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

after an async gap, there is a possibility that your widget is no longer mounted. thats why `context` is not recommended to use across an async gap. But if you are so sure that your widget is still mounted then, according to flutter team which you can check [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzWaMpD1LHY&ab_channel=Flutter), the recommended approach is to store the context before the await keyword. In your case, this is how it should be done:

```html
   Future<void> login(BuildContext context,String username, String password) async {
      final nav = Navigator.of(context);
    showDialog(context);
    var result = await authenticate(username,password);
    int type = await getUserType(result);
    nav.pop(); // to hide progress dialog
    if(type == 1){
       nav.pushReplacementNamed('a');
    }else if(type == 2){
        nav.pushReplacementNamed('b');
     
    }
  }
```